# how to use TIMESTAMP and DATETIME functions when running parameterized queries in bigquery cli?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm using [this][1] as a reference and I came up with this script:

```
bq --location=US query --use_legacy_sql=False \
--parameter = 'ts_value:TIMESTAMP:TIMESTAMP_SUB(TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)),interval 5 hour)' \ 
--parameter = 'ts_value2:TIMESTAMP:TIMESTAMP_SUB(TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 2 DAY)),interval 5 hour)' \
'with base_query as (
    select * from table1 t1
    inner join table2 t2
    on 
    t1._id = t2.table1_id
    where mydate >= @ts_value2 and mydate <@ts_value
),
another_query as (
    select * from table3
    where this_Date = @ts_value
)

select bq.*,aq.*;'
```

but it is giving me an error

Answer (score 1):

> What am I doing wrong?

You are trying to add SQL function logic into your parameters which should hold a literal value.

I would change this:

```
--parameter = 'ts_value:TIMESTAMP:TIMESTAMP_SUB(TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)),interval 5 hour)' \
```

To this:

```
--parameter = 'ts_value:INT64:5' \
```

And your query, for `@ts_value`, to this:

```
with base_query as (
    select * from table1 t1
    inner join table2 t2
    on 
    t1._id = t2.table1_id
    where mydate >= @ts_value2 and mydate < TIMESTAMP_SUB(TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)),interval @ts_value hour)
),
another_query as (
    select * from table3
    where this_Date = @ts_value
)

select bq.*,aq.*;
```

Note: You need to add your other variable also to get a full working SQL

Comment: @Abdullah, hope my answer helped you important on SO - you can mark accepted answer by using the tick on the left of the posted answer, below the voting. See meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/… for why it is important!